Where to report income from 1042s on 1040-NR as an Indian citizen for 2023?
I have scholarship/fellowship income in my 1042s that's not reported in my W2 form. However in the 1040NR for the year 2023, there doesn't seem to be a box to report this income. Where do I report it?

You can report it on Schedule 1 line 8r (it goes to 1040NR line 10).
